# Community countdown event for March for Science

Tags: discussion

The [March for Science](https://www.marchforscience.com/) is an event/protest/rally being held on April 22, 2017. The main march will occur in Washington D.C., but there will be marches all over the world and across the United States. There is an SE chat room dedicated to the march. As many of our community members are scientists and/or support science, I was wondering if we wanted a community event countdown to be shown on the main page. As the event is somewhat political in nature, I wanted to check with the community before creating an event. The countdown timer is not overbearing and is just a small item on the side bar.

---

A response to potential objections:

> This march is something relevant only to the United States.

Nope. While the main march is occurring in D.C., there will be marches all around the world (see [here](https://www.marchforscience.com/satellite-marches/)).

> This is an overally political thing to promote.

While it is political, many scientific organizations are endorsing it, such as the AAAS (which publishes Science magazine), the American Geophysical Union (AGU), and the American Statistical Association (ASA) - you can read more about which organizations are endorsing it [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/02/will-they-or-won-t-they-what-science-groups-are-saying-about-joining-march-science).

> A community ad will be a much better way to promote this issue.

Well, for starters, I did create a community ad (as did someone else; my version was downvoted to oblivion, theirs is at -2). However, I think this event is important enough that it's worth advertising beyond just a community ad. Also, I might point out again that the countdown timer is just a small item on the side bar, so it won't interfere with normal use.

---

Note: some of this (the introduction) was pulled from [an equivalent post over on Academia.SE](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3690/community-countdown-event-for-march-for-science).

Comment: Somewhat political?

Comment: Clearly misnamed; should be April for Science.

Comment: What is the march supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Note: it may be worth looking at [this page](https://www.marchforscience.com/mission-and-vision) which details more eloquently than I can the march's mission and goals.

Comment: I removed a bunch of comments that strayed into the aggressively political and/or were obsolete. Let me suggest that we keep the discussion away from the merits of the march itself here. "No, I don't want it here because I don't agree with its goals/assumptions/whatever" is a valid position as is "Yes, I want it here and agree with its goals" and also "No, because I don't think we should advertise such events on principle", and that's all the input this meta posts asks for -  should this be advertised as a community event or not? It does *not* call for a general discussion of the march itself.

Comment: I might point out (jumping off ACuriousMind's point) that no one has really explained their reasoning in downvoting (disagreeing) with this meta post.

Comment: I downvoted because the march is propaganda based on fear and has nothing to do with this site or its policies.

Comment: (-1) First, Physics.SE should not be used as a platform to advertise external agendas - even a majority consensus falsely associates 'goals/assumptions/whatever' on the entire community.  Second, and unrelated to my vote, I disagree with the premise of the march.

Comment: Last, comments are courteous, nothing else.  Its misleading to imply that downvotes are unjustified if lacking explanation.

Comment: @theNamesCross, I implied no such thing; I was merely curious to see reasoning. Clearly, this is not as uncontroversial as I thought it would be.

Comment: @heather Anything venturing into politics will, always, be controversial.

Comment: Heather, I think this will be d/V enough without me adding to them. But IMO, it's awfully vague as to it's objectives. The new leader of the free world (that's now Angela Merkel,  no only half  kidding) has achieved his position because he kept his (abhorrent to me) message simple, the march for science needs to somehow do the same. Political messages and slogans are always better if they can be written on a placard, if the organisers can do that, they will get somewhere, but not based on reasoned arguments on a far too long website page. Ok, rant done.

Comment: I would like to mention [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/18344) post as an argument for the essentially politicial characteristic of the demonstration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community events, as they're called, are used for advertising events happening *within the SE network*. The URL associated with each event [has to be a Stack Exchange URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285947/allow-non-se-urls-in-community-events), which poses a technical restriction on using such an event for something happening outside SE, but even discounting the technical restriction, we should consider the intent of the SE developers in providing this feature and their reasons for doing it that way. Community events are supposed to be used for advertising things that are relevant for the community's participation *on this site*. The March for Science may be relevant to a lot of people here, but it's not relevant to how they participate in Stack Exchange, so I don't believe it deserves the privileged position of being advertised in the community bulletin (that's the proper name for the yellow sidebar).

If there were, say, a chat event associated with the march happening simultaneously, that would be a different matter. Chat events are fine candidates for advertising in the bulletin.

SE doesn't really give us a good way to advertise external events. The closest we come is community ads, but they're better suited for permanent things, not events that occur at a specific time and then are done with.